# When to use a nested array versus using a separate collection

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose

I need to use mongoose with dbref but I don't know which design is better for me.

First design:

```
var user = mongoose.Schema({
    name: 'string'
});

var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: 'string',
    propietary_id: 'String',
    comments : [{
        text: 'string',
        user: { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'users' },
        createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now }  
    }]
});
```

Second design:

```
var user = mongoose.Schema({
    name: 'string'
});

var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: 'string',
    propietary_id: 'String'
});

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: 'string',
    event_id : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'events' },
    user_id : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'users' },
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now }  
});
```

How it works? On my website there is an event list and if you want to see comments you have to click every event, then angularjs gets all comments (text, user name and user photo) of the selected events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pros and cons with both solutions and the best one for you depends on your usage. Remember that you can produce exactly the same API independent of your design it only comes down to how quickly and easily you can maintain the backend. First some thoughts on both designs:

---

### **First design:**

First a comment, I wouldn't save comments as a nested document but as an array instead. Otherwise you are limited to one comment per event. Use this schema instead:

```
comments: [
    {
        text: { type: String },
        user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'users' },
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    }
]
```

*Pros:*

- No need for multiple collections
- You will have the comments returned with the event in the get request which will mean less requests to your backend
- No need to map comments to events

*Cons:*

- You will have the comments returned to you with the event, even if you don't want them displayed
- If there are a lot of comments to an event, the request response will be pretty large
- If you want to remove or edit comments in your array it will be trickier (not impossible though)

---

### **Second design:**

*Pros:*

- You will have the events and comments separated which means leaner objects
- You can much easier extract one comment for edit or delete
- You can more easily get events without comments and then request comments at another point

*Cons:*

- You will need to always map comments to events which will mean more code
- Two collections will mean two requests usually
- Maintenance of another collection

---

### **Verdict:**

All the pros and cons are judged by how much extra code you need to write. Of course you can always have comments returned with your events in the second design as well but then you will have the extract the comments first and returned them with the event object which will mean extra code to maintain.

I think the second design would work better for you. I'm judging this by your comment that you will only need comments if the user click on an event. I would then be requesting the events first and do another request for comments as soon as the user click on the event, however, having the comments always be returned with the events should make the ui more snappy as the comments will already have been loaded.

It all depends in the end what is more important for you to do with the data. Please let me know if you have any questions on any of the points.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's possible return object with events information, 2 comments and total number of comments? in this query.
Events.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, obj) {
  res.json(obj);
 });

Comment: You can do another stack question for that and send it to me because it's too little space to answer here :P but inside your Events.findOne callback you can find all comments belonging to the vent and return them in the response. If you want a more in depth answer you need to write another stack quest and post it here.

Comment: this is the new ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836360/show-comments-like-facebook-with-express